# How can I set global options for Intl.DateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript, date

How can I set globally default format options (e.g on app start), so that i see always two-digits for month and day?

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 1, 3, 0, 0));
// Results below assume UTC timezone - your results may vary

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }).format(date));
// expected output: "12/01/2012"

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }).format(date));
// expected output: "01/12/2012"

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-DE', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }).format(date));
// expected output: "01.12.2012"
```

Following is the default behavior used by the INTL API (one digit)

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 1, 3, 0, 0));
// Results below assume UTC timezone - your results may vary

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date));
// expected output: "12/1/2012"

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date));
// expected output: "01/12/2012"

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-DE').format(date));
// expected output: "1.12.2012"
```